Security microservice spring cloud geteway
I have three microservices A, B and C (a geteway spring cloud)
Here is my configuration:

Microservice A :

Configuration Class
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .headers(h -> h.frameOptions(fo -> fo.disable()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(ar-> ar.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(o2rs -> o2rs.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter)))
                .build();
    }


Microservice B :

Configuration Class
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .headers(h -> h.frameOptions(fo -> fo.disable()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(ar-> ar.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(o2rs -> o2rs.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter)))
                .build();
    }


Microservice C (geteway):
NO Configuration Class

Properties file:
spring:
  application.name: backend-gateway-client
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      routes:
        - id: resources
          uri: http://localhost:8082/messages
          predicates:
            Path=/messages/**
        - id: customer
          uri: http://localhost:8086/
          predicates:
            Path=/customers/**
        
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: my-provider
            client-id: front-end-angular-client
            client-secret: xWskwS0avQaf1rLOwqdUDhROopWoOjWl
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://localhost:8083/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: openid
        provider:
          my-provider:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8081/realms/ecom-web-app


Classe globalFilter
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)

public class CustomGlobalFilter implements GlobalFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        // Récupérer le token depuis l'en-tête de la requête
        String token = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");
        
        if (isAuthenticated(exchange.getRequest())) {
            // Utilisation déjà authentifié, laissez la requête passer
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        } else {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "http://localhost:4200);
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }
    }

In the geteway, I have a global filter which allows you to verify the token before authenticating, i.e.
if token yes: we do not authenticate.
If token no: we authenticate.
My problem, authentication always comes before filter despite the global filter filter
CURRENT SCENARIO: request => authentication => FILTER
DESIRED SCENARIO: request => filter => authentication (yes/no)
I can't find a solution, does anyone have an idea?
Thank you.
CURRENT SCENARIO: request => authentication => FILTER
DESIRED SCENARIO: request => filter => authentication (yes/no)

As it is configured as an OAuth2 client with oauth2Login, requests to your gateway are authorized with session cookies. Only requests forwarded with the TokenRelay filter for users with an authorized session on the gateway are authorized with access tokens.
If some of the apps upfront the gateway are OAuth2 clients and send requests with access tokens already, you should define two separate SecurityWebFilterChain on the gateway: one with oauth2Login for the apps needing user authentication (single-page and mobile apps), and another one without oauth2Login for other apps.
